# DASH callback function recognises literal value, but not formula

Tags: plotly-dash

The following simple DASH callback has no effect:

@app.callback(

```
Output(component_id='Energy slider',component_property='value'),
[Input(component_id='Angular Momentum Slider',component_property='value')]
)
```

def update_energy_slider(NewEnergySV):

```
Vmin = -((k**2)*μ)/((2*(NewEnergySV*(10**33))**2))

return max(Vmin,((e**2)-1)*μ*(k**2)/(2*((NewEnergySV*(10**33))**2)))/(10**33)
```

However, if I replace the formula in the return statement with its actual literal value - i.e.

```
return -2.65
```

...it works fine.

Any ideas anyone?